# sklearn OneHotEncoding with ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

l have categorical data on column 8 of my dataset. l wish to encode this data and l am using ColumnTransformer. The first time l tried to use this method l used the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

#encoding categorical data for dept column(independent variables)
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('one_hot_encoder',OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), [0])],
                       remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

Kindly note that l am using LabelEncoder to encode my dependent variable and this is working perfectly. Now the problem is when l executed this code the first time there was no error but when l change the column index to say [8] in my case, l get an error pertaining to index [0].
*ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Emp ID'*
This l think raises two issues, first that my column heading is not being read as such and secondly, that the index is not being changed to 8.

l have added:`drop='first'` with the hope of dropping column [0] but to no avail

Comment: Please include some sample/structure of your table `X`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use Keras to_categorical

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

X = to_categorical(X)
```